# laravel image validation sometimes works

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple validation rule, to just require a photo being uploaded
yet, some images go through no problem, and some of them tell me, 'image required'.

Am I missing something in my code? what would let some get through and some not?

```
// getting all of the post data
$file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));

// setting up rules
rules = array('image' => 'required',);
```

Comment: is this in the `validate()` function?  because you can try this. `'sometimes|image'`. if that works for you, than when you upload your images, you didn't set the extension properly, i guess.

Comment: Right now, I just want to make sure there is something in the upload. I don't care what file type it is.